# Not sure how to make a script that displays the content the users submit on main page

Tags: forms

I'm not sure how to go about making this script. I will have a submit form for users and I want what they submit to be posted on the main page of the site. Can someone tell me what language i'd have to do this in to make it happen? I am a noob (well it's obvious) and ive been doing research and im just stuck right now. or if there are scripts that are already made for that, that would be helpful also. An example would be... sort of how on a blog.. well tumblr, users submit content and that content gets displayed.. ok maybe thats a bad example but hopefully you all get the idea on what im looking for. also, not asking for anyone to do it. just any tips would be nice on how to do this would be very nice and appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your question will be a bit tough to answer since 'Script' is vague.  What 'script' do you mean?  Javascript, VBScript, C# Script?  There are so many.  Can you please expand your question a bit more?

Comment: thanks! and... the problem is i wasnt sure which of those to actually use for this project that's why i didnt clarify. sorry about that. im still in the learning stages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what user post is permanent then you definitely need *server side scripting* language. ***ie: PHP, JSP***, etc.. along with some ***HTML***, some ***Javascript***, some ***CSS***. At this stage, I would recommend ***PHP*** for you. Because it is easy to learn for beginners.

Because of the *inability* and *non-recommendation* of client side scripting languages such as JS to communicate with databases, server side scripting languages are used to communicate with databases for many reasons. Because of which, what user post can be stored in the database permanently through server side scripting. Once it is stored in the database, you can show that content on any of your webpages anytime.

**Tutorials:**

**How to install PHP, MySql:** http://www.techmalaya.com/2007/09/10/beginners-guide-install-php-5-mysql-5-on-apache-22-on-windows-with-screenshots/

**Learn PHP for beginners:** http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: Thanks. I have figured out how to display data submittd into a mysql database.